# Number of ways to write a number $n$ as a product of $3$ natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics

For $2$ it's easy, for the first number we have $f$ (the number of factors the number $n$ has) possibilities and the second is a filler to the number n, so only one possibility for each, but we counted twice so the formula is $\frac{f}{2}$. I tried to do it for $3$. For the first number if we choose the lowest factor we have $f$ possibilities for the second number, if we choose the second lowest factor we have $f-1$ possibilities and so on, and for the third number we have only one possibility for each because it's a filler to the number $n$, but we counted everything $3!$ times so the final formula would be $\frac{f(f+1)}{12}$. I have tested this formula and it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your calculation for $2$ fails when $n$ is a square.

Comment: Is repetition allowed?

Comment: @lulu You're right. Maybe just rounding it up will do?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar No, repetition is not allowed, we assume that $(1,1,n)$ and $(1,n,1)$ is the same

Comment: Well, I'd say it was best (or at least more clear) to remove the square root case prior to dividing.

Comment: For $3$, what if $n = p^3$ and $p$ is a prime?

Comment: On first pass, it looks hard to handle the symmetries.  Even for a prime power....

Comment: Do you want $\frac {f(f-1)}{12}$ or $\frac {f(f+1)}{12}$ as you gave in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ the number $N_n$ of triples $(n_1,n_2,n_3)\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}^3$ satisfying $n_1\cdot n_2\cdot n_3=n$ is obtained as follows: Let
$$n=p_1^{m_1}\cdot p_2^{m_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{m_r}$$
be the prime decomposition of $n$. Then
$$N_n=\prod_{k=1}^r{m_k+2\choose2}\ .$$
Unfortunately this is not what you want, since triples differing only by a permutation should be considered the same.

For the correct bookkeeping we first have to count separately the factorings of the form $n=n_1^2\, n_2$ and $n=n_1^3$. This will involve the divisibility of the $m_k$ by $2$ and $3$. Then each triple $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ of our first counting will have to be weighed in by the factor ${1\over6}$, if it contains three different factors, by the factor ${1\over3}$ if it has two equal entries, and by the factor $1$ if it has three equal entries. The latter can only happen if all $m_k$ are divisible by $3$.